# Problems with building hector navigation

Tags: slam, navigation, hector, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package costmap_2d.

  Set costmap_2d_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for costmap_2d.  The file will have one of the following names:

    costmap_2dConfig.cmake
    costmap_2d-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  hector_navigation/hector_exploration_planner/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package nav_core.

  Set nav_core_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
  nav_core.  The file will have one of the following names:

    nav_coreConfig.cmake
    nav_core-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  hector_navigation/hector_exploration_planner/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_exploration_node'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_navigation/hector_exploration_node)
CMake Error at /home/gordon/catkin_ws/devel/share/hector_exploration_planner/cmake/hector_exploration_plannerConfig.cmake:165 (find_package):
  Could not find module Findcostmap_2d.cmake or a configuration file for
  package costmap_2d.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find Findcostmap_2d.cmake or set costmap_2d_DIR
  to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for costmap_2d.  The
  file will have one of the following names:

    costmap_2dConfig.cmake
    costmap_2d-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package)
  hector_navigation/hector_exploration_node/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at /home/gordon/catkin_ws/devel/share/hector_exploration_planner/cmake/hector_exploration_plannerConfig.cmake:165 (find_package):
  Could not find module Findnav_core.cmake or a configuration file for
  package nav_core.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find Findnav_core.cmake or set nav_core_DIR to
  the directory containing a CMake configuration file for nav_core.  The file
  will have one of the following names:

    nav_coreConfig.cmake
    nav_core-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package)
  hector_navigation/hector_exploration_node/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_costmap'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_navigation/hector_costmap)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package pcl_conversions.

  Set pcl_conversions_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
  file for pcl_conversions.  The file will have one of the following names:

    pcl_conversionsConfig.cmake
    pcl_conversions-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  hector_navigation/hector_costmap/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_elevation_mapping'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_navigation/hector_elevation_mapping)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211221/problems-with-building-hector-navigation/) by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-06-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try:

> apt-get install ros-indigo-navigation

It contains the costmap_2d package. I also had to install ros-indigo-pcl-conversions and ros-indigo-pcl-ros to finally get the hector-navigation stack to work. This is all assuming you have ROS Indigo installed of course. Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [cqm4061](https://answers.ros.org/users/22848/cqm4061/) with karma: 106 on 2015-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-06-23**:
Yes! It works! Thanks a lot!